# Inodes in External Disk full. Actually not

Tags: linux, bash, unix, filesystems, rsync

Checking inode usage:

```
[cold] > df -ih .
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1         59M   59M  7.9K  100% /home/doom/cold
```

Here we see 100% Inode usage. 59 million inodes used.

But if I try to check inode used per directory we get:
(using find command in the mounted disk)

```
[cold] > find . -printf "%h\n"|grep -v "^/proc"|grep -v "^/sys"|cut -d\/ -f1-3|sort|uniq -c|sort -rn

  20581 ./zzz/all_repos
  16994 ./Media/photos
   4898 ./zzz/files
   4135 ./zzz/rog_sync
```

Here max number is 20k. How can df -i show 59 million usage.

**Notes:**
I got above `find` command on the net to check folder wise inode usage. Adding all the inodes does not even reach 100k.

**More Notes:**
Actually I wanted to make this drive as backup for my entire system, so I rsynced `/` to it last month. After that this issue. But even after I deleted all the backed up files on this drive. This still show 100% inodes used.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: What filesystem is this disk using?

Comment: Try this command : `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1 | grep -i inode`. In the worst case, just reformat the disk.

Comment: @harrymc 
Getting this:
`[~] > sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1 | grep -i inode`
`Filesystem features:     has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum`

Inode count:              61054976
Free inodes:              61054841
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Journal inode:            8
Journal backup:           inode blocks

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you ran the `tune2fs` command with the folowing results :

```
> sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1 | grep -i inode
Filesystem features:     has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Inode count: 61054976
Free inodes: 61054841
Inodes per group: 8192
Inode blocks per group: 512
First inode: 11
Inode size: 256
Journal inode: 8
Journal backup: inode blocks
```

My conclusion is that the the disk is basically empty with 99.9% of
free inodes.

I don't know why the `df` command fails for this disk, but the information
it shows you is simply incorrect. There is a very good chance that there
is nothing wrong with the disk, but still better keep your backups.

Comment: I don't know if [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406762/108618) is true. What if it is?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Interesting - good idea to do what that linked answer suggests, to unmount the disk and do again tune2fs. However, it seems funny that the poster has deleted a lot of files but inodes still remains at 100% used. If true, it might signal a failing disk.

Comment: my disk gone crazy